# Same file path and files in LabVIEW

Tags: labview

I saved the data in txt file. Everything is ok. Now, I want to show the data on the chart then that data send by email.

First, I select the txt file from the dialog and then show it on the chart or graph which is ok till here. Then, I want to attach that file automatically and after 5 sec sends it to a specific email. my problem is that I don't want to create a control for attach to choose the txt file, I want to select once the file , then read, then that file email.

Normally, I must select once to read and another time again to select that file (2 times) but I want to select one time the txt file then read and after 5 sec that file attaches and email. I cannot connect attach file wire (RED Wire) to the file dialog because the type of attach is 1D array file path and the type of file dialog is path, I don't know what should I do.

Thanks for helping me.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use `Build Array` function to convert your single path (which goes from path select dialog) to 1D array of paths.